# Unique continuation property for operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, terminology

Let $A$ be an operator. What does mean, roughly speaking, that $A$ satysfies the unique continuation property?

On my notes I read that it means that if $A(x_n) = B(x_n)$, where $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a convergent sequence in the doamain of $A$ and $B$, then $A(x) = B(x)$ for all $x$ in the domain of $A$ and $B$.

It is not so clear for me, could anyone please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One version maybe as follows,

**Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces and $A:X\longrightarrow Y$ and $B:X\longrightarrow Y$ be two continuous map. Let $X'$ be a dense subset of $X$ (in other words, every open subset of $X$ contains at least one element of $X'$). If for any convergent sequence $(x_n)$ in $X'$ we have, $A(x_n)=B(x_n)$ $\forall$ $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we must have $A(x)=B(x)$ $\forall$ $x\in X$.**